# Verilog decoder when input is 'X'

Tags: logic, verilog, decoder, digital

I'm trying to make a 3-to-9 decoder in Verilog. The module works as expected in simulation, however only when the input is well defined. When the input is 'X' the outputs are also 'X'. This kinda makes sense, but is there a way to assign values to the outputs even if the input is 'X', or 'Z' for that matter? Something like a reset, perhaps? Following is the template of the decoder,

```
always @*
begin
case(3_bit_input)
    3'b000 : begin /*assign outputs*/ end

    3'b001 : begin /*assign outputs*/ end

    3'b010 : begin  /*assign outputs*/ end
    .
    .   
    .
    .
    .
    3'b111 : begin  /*assign outputs*/ end
endcase
end
```

Comment: actually in your case when the input is 'x' the value of the output just does not change. If it was 'x', it will be 'x', if it was something else, it will remain this something.  The case will behave as a latch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a `default:` label to branch when the input does not exactly any other label. It a good idea to have it anytime you have not exhaustively considered every possible value.

But trying to deal with X's in dynamic simulation can be a losing battle.

Comment: I actually tried adding a default: label, but it still didn't work during post-synthesis simulation. Is that normal?

Comment: This is expected. X propagation get even worse in gate-level simulation. That's because there's only one `X` state. In real hardware you can perform operations like subtraction and equality with an unknown state on itself to get into a known state. But dynamic simulation does not track the source of the X to know when it converges. Only formal static checking tools can do that.

Comment: You have to remember that 'x' is just an *unknown* value. In your case it is not electrically possible, since you listed all possible combinations of the input. 'X' just means one of those combinations. The synthesis will take an advantage of it and generate a correct schematic. So, the 'default' clause would be just a *simulation* artifact.